# Setting up an 'environment' for an embedded Lua Script

Tags: c++, scripting, lua

I am embedding a Lua interpreter in a C++ application.

I want to setup an 'environment' for running scripts, such that certain variables are made available to all scripts.

For example, I want to expose READ ONLY objects Foo and FooBar to scripts, such that Foo and FooBar are available to all running scripts.

Does anyone know how I can do this?. A snippet to show how to so this would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard of read-only variables in Lua but you can prevent modification by making the environment available via a function call instead.

If the C++ application is large, you will probably want to use a tool to generate an interface you can call from Lua. I have used tolua++ in the past with some luck:

Suppose `demo.hpp` is a header file of the C++ application:

```
#ifndef SO_DEMO_HPP
#define SO_DEMO_HPP

namespace demo
{
    class Foo
    {
        double x;

    public:
        Foo(double x) : x(x) {}
        double getX() const { return x; }
    };

    Foo* getFoo();
}

#endif
```

Implement `demo::getFoo()` in `demo.cpp`.

`demo.pkg` lists the things that should be callable from Lua:

```
$#include "demo.hpp"

namespace demo
{
    class Foo
    {
        double getX() const;
    };

    Foo* getFoo();
}
```

Generate `demo_stub.cpp` and `demo_stub.hpp` files containing our Lua module:

```
$ tolua++5.1 -o demo_stub.cpp -H demo_stub.hpp demo.pkg
```

`main.cpp` is a Lua interpreter that loads the `demo` module:

```
#include "demo.hpp"

extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <tolua++.h>
}
#include "demo_stub.hpp"

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = lua_open();

    luaL_openlibs(L);
    tolua_demo_open(L);

    if (luaL_dofile(L, NULL) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

The `tolua_demo_open()` function was generated by tolua++ and is declared in `demo_stub.hpp`.

Build a Lua interpreter named `demo`:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include/lua5.1 demo.cpp demo_stub.cpp main.cpp -ltolua++5.1 -llua5.1 -o demo
```

Construct a `demo.lua` script

```
print("Hello, world!")
print(tolua.type(demo.getFoo()))
print(demo.getFoo():getX())
```

and feed the script to the interpreter:

```
$ ./demo < demo.lua
Hello, world!
demo::Foo
42
```

Comment: @autonakos: Thanks for the code. It will definitely help set me on the right path (I still need to experiment some more).

Answer (score 0):

[`lua_setglobal`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setglobal).

As for 'read only', do you mean that that Foo will not be overwritable (e.g. `Foo = 10`), or that the *value* Foo reverse will be immutable (e.g. `Foo.x = 10`)?